# Validation error messages are not displaying in Rails 3

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I have one issue with rails validation.I have validated all fields in model file but when i am putting some wrong data no error message is displaying.As my form contains Rails's ajax call also i am getting the all field value in rendered html page.check my code below.

vendor_add.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for :vendor,:url => {:action => "create_vendor" },remote: true do |f| %>
    <% if @vendor.errors.any? %>
    <div id="error_explanation">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@vendor.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this post from being saved:</h2>

      <ul>
      <% @vendor.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
        <li><%= msg %></li>
      <% end %>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
    <div class="block-content">
        <div class="timeline-container">
            <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Registration No :</div></span>
            <%= f.text_field :reg_no ,:class => "form-control",:id => "reg" %>
              </div>
              <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left" ><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Date &amp; Time :</div></span>
              <%= f.text_field :dat ,:class => "form-control add-on",placeholder:"Date &amp; Time",:required => true,:id => 'datetimepicker4',:onclick => "get_date();" %>
              </div>
            <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Name :</div></span>
             <%= f.text_field :v_name ,:class => "form-control",placeholder:"Name",:required => true %>
              </div>
              <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Father Name :</div></span>
              <%= f.text_field :f_name ,:class => "form-control",placeholder:"Father Name",:required => true %>
              </div>
              <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left" ><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Date of Birth :</div></span>
              <%= f.text_field :dob ,:class => "form-control add-on",placeholder:"Date of Birth",:required => true,:id => "dp2",:onclick => "get_dob();" %>
              </div>
              <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Mob. No :</div></span>
               <%= f.text_field :mob_no ,:class => "form-control",placeholder:"Mob. No",:required => true %>
              </div>
              <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"><span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Address :</div></span>
               <%= f.text_field :v_address ,:class => "form-control",placeholder:"Address",:required => true %>
              </div>
              <div class="input-group bmargindiv1 col-md-6 pull-left"> <span class="input-group-addon text-left"><div class="leftsidetextwidth">Service Category :</div></span>
              <%= f.select(:s_catagory,options_for_select([['Wood','Wood'],['Puja Samagree','Puja Samagree'],['Sweeper','Sweeper'],['Photo Grapher','Photo Grapher'],['Burning Assistant','Burning Assistant'],['BRAHMIN','BRAHMIN']]),{:prompt => "Select type" },{:class => 'form-control'}) %>
              </div>
              <div class="clearfix"></div>
              <div class="tbpaddingdiv1 text-center">
                <%= f.submit "Submit",:class => "btn btn-success" %>
              </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <% end %>
```

> Vendor.rb:

```
class Vendor < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :dat, :dob, :f_name, :mob_no, :reg_no, :s_catagory, :v_address, :v_name
  validates :v_name, :presence => true,:length => {:minimum => 3}
  validates :f_name, :presence => true,:length => {:minimum => 3}
  validates :mob_no, :presence => true, :length => {:in => 1..10},format: { with: /\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/, message: "bad format" }
  validates :dob,  :date => {:before => Time.now  }
  validates :s_catagory,:presence =>  true
end
```

> vendors_controller.rb:

```
class VendorsController < ApplicationController
    def vendor_add
        @vendor=Vendor.new
        if params[:v_id]
            @vendor=Vendor.find(params[:v_id])
        end
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.js
        end
    end
    def create_vendor
        if params[:vendor][:s_catagory]=="Wood"
            catagory="Woods"
        elsif params[:vendor][:s_catagory]=="Puja Samagree"
            catagory="GOODS"
        elsif params[:vendor][:s_catagory]=="Sweeper"
            catagory="SWD"
        elsif params[:vendor][:s_catagory]=="Photo Grapher"
            catagory="PHOTO"
        elsif params[:vendor][:s_catagory]=="Burning Assistant"
            catagory="BURNING"
        else
            catagory="BRAHMIN"
        end 
        @vendor= Vendor.create(:v_name => params[:vendor][:v_name],:v_address => params[:vendor][:v_address],:reg_no => params[:vendor][:reg_no],:f_name => params[:vendor][:f_name],:mob_no => params[:vendor][:mob_no],:dob => params[:vendor][:dob],:s_catagory => catagory,:dat => params[:vendor][:dat] )  
        if  @vendor
            flash[:notice]="Vendor data has submitted"
            flash[:color]="valid"
        else
            flash[:alert]="Data could not submit"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'vendor_add'
        end
    end
    def vendor_edit
        @vendor=Vendor.find(params[:v_id])
    end
    def update_vendor
        @vendor=Vendor.find(params[:v_id])
        if @vendor.update_attributes(params[:vendor])
            flash[:notice]="Vendor data has updated"
            flash[:color]="valid"
        else
            flash[:alert]="Data could not submit"
            flash[:color]="invalid"
            render 'vendor_add',:v_id => params[:v_id]
        end
    end
end
```

> create_vendor.js.erb:

```
$("#vendor-total-div").css("display", "block");
$("#vendor-div").html("<%= escape_javascript (render 'vendor_output_table' ) %>");
$("#vendor-div").slideDown(350);
```

> _vendor_output_table.html.erb:

```
<table class="table table-bordered">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                    <th class="text-center">Sl. No</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Date</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Registration No</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Name</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Mob. No</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Service Category</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Status</th>
                    <th class="text-center">Action</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= @vendor.id %></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= @vendor.dat %></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= @vendor.reg_no %></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= @vendor.v_name %></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= @vendor.mob_no %></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= @vendor.s_catagory %></td>
                    <td class="text-center"><%= @vendor.id %></td>
                    <td class="text-center">
                        <div class="btn-group">
                            <a href="/vendor_add?v_id=<%= @vendor.id %>" class="btn btn-xs btn-success" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Edit">
                                <i class="fa fa-edit"></i>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
                </table>
```

I also cannot know even if the above page is rendering but how @vendor object is creating before submit data in DB.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Where are you displaying the error messages? example `<%= @user.errors.full_messages.first if @user.errors.any? %>`

Comment: @ Cyzanfar : It is present in vendor_add.html.erb.Chcek my first code file above.

Comment: Opps my bad... thanks for pointing to it

Comment: In you `vendor_add` method, you are not rendering anything if the adding fails.That might be the problem.

Comment: @ Cyzanfar : yes,I am rendering one table containing the input data after saved in db for this action.

Comment: @Cyzanfar :Can you extract the solution for this issue.

Comment: `def vendor_add
  @my_model = MyModel.new(my_model_params)
  if @my_model.save
    redirect_to 'blabla'
  else
    render :new
  end
end`
so here if it fails you should be back on the same page with error msg displayed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76983/discussion-between-satya-and-cyzanfar).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@satya, We have two option either you can replace **if @vendor** under  def create_vendor to -

1)**if @vendor and @vendor.id.present?**

2) **if @vendor and @vendor.errors.blank? and @vendor.errors.messages.blank?**

because create method always return the object either saved or not based on the validation!

Or

You can use the save instead of create because save will give you true or false not will return the object!

Comment: @ Chitra : yes,you are correct .I can also understand your lines.But one thing I can not display the validation error messages.Can you please help me for this part  ?

Comment: @satya, have you checked the errors by using debugger. Does  vendor.errors.any?  is giving true? and please paste what vandor.errors is giving .....

Comment: @ Chitra : I got success to display validation error messages.Thanks for your help.